# add class when scroll to a div, remove class when scroll to another div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/159/)

I'm trying to make a table header become fixed when scrolling to the table by adding a class `fixed_header` and removing the class when scrolling past the table.

The following code is able to add the class when scrolling to `#start_body`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 525) {
      var s_body = $('#start_body').offset();
      var e_body = $('#end_body').offset();
      $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(y >= s_body.top){
          $('table thead').addClass('fixed_header');
        }
        else if(y < e_body.top) // what condition should I use?
        {
          $('table thead').removeClass('fixed_header');
        }
    })
  }
 }).resize();
})
```

But how can I remove the class when scrolling to `#end_body`?

HTML:

```
<div class='jk'></div><div id='start_body'><h3>Start</h3>
 <table>
    <thead><tr><th>Age</th><th>Gender</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>12</td><td>M</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td><td>F</td></tr>
        <tr><td>12</td><td>M</td></tr>
        <tr><td>14</td><td>F</td></tr>   
        ..........
    </tbody>
 </table>    
</div>
<div id='end_body'>
    <h3>End</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: The issues is that the first conditional is always true even when you go past the end of the table so you never enter the else block. Make the condition check you are between the start and end values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgk1t9gb/)

```
if(y >= s_body.top && y < e_body.top){
      $('table thead').addClass('fixed_header');
    }
    else 
    {
      $('table thead').removeClass('fixed_header');
    }
```